# Is there any way to capture the metrics without re recording and compare the results between 2 builds or version of application

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have thoroughly gone through the document: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference

How to capture the  metrics of performance panel for the different version of app for the same scenario?

What I am trying to achieve I don't won't record same scenario for different versions of build of application.Some times I may miss step.

For ex:  Here is my senario or test case

1. Login
2. Do some action
3. Logot

For some xxxx version of app

I have saved the performance panel results.

Now devs made some of  performance improvements and asked to do the same test of zzzz version of same application.

So do indeed to record and analyze the results that’s only the way?

Is there any way to capture the metrics without re recording and compare the results between 2 builds or version of application.

Comment: Sounds like you want to have the metrics of an action without actually performing that action. Not possible.

Comment: @wOxxOm  let me put it this I want to capture the metrics with out re recording of different build of application meaning I have captured metrics earlier on earlier version of application and saved the profile

Comment: @wOxxOm   What I mean to say I am trying to replay the same scenario /  steps and capture the metrics. Record once replay and capture metrics  as dev deploys new version of. Application under test.

Comment: DevTools can't do that. Maybe there's a custom tool built on Selenium or Puppeteer or similar.